# Rails variable loads first time and then is nil!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, null, actionview

I am receiving the following error:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.include?) on line #24 of app/views/index/index.html.erb:
21: <% @achievements.each do |achievement| %>
22:     <%= achievement.name %>
23:     <%= achievement.level %>
24:     by <%= achievement.user.username %><br/>
25: <% end %>
```

The strange thing is that when the index page is loaded the first time then there is no problem whatsoever.  When I refresh, I get the error above.

The controller looks like this:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @achievements = Achievement.find(:all)
    end
end
```

Is it something to do with the caching? Or is it using too much memory?  If so, can I load the username in another way perhaps? I'm confused!

Comment: show your controller action here

Comment: controller action added above

Comment: Try eager loading the users by adding ":include => :user" in your find (Achievement.find(:all, :include => :user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try eager loading the users by adding ":include => :user" in your find:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @achievements = Achievement.find(:all, :include => :user)
    end
end
```